# Resizing an SVG using GIMP

Tags: vector, gimp, svg

I exported an image from this site https://watabou.itch.io/medieval-fantasy-city-generator and am trying to make it really big, but can't figure out how. The tutorial vid I found uses an iOS or modified UI and I can't follow it. How do I resize this image, these paths, or whatever?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. GIMP isn't an SVG editor, by any stretch of the imagination.  Use Inkscape instead. It's also free and Open Source

Answer (score 7):

1. Use Inkscape which is meant to edit SVG graphics
2. With Gimp (if the SVG is only the beginning for a final raster image). Several solutions (they assume that you have ticked the "Import paths` option in the SVG open dialog):

   - If you do `File>Open` and select an SVG file, you can change the resolution, and this changes the size of the imported image. So you can scale up by just increasing the resolution.
   - Once the image is loaded, `Image>Scale image` with scale everything, including the imported paths.
   - You can also scale just one path, using the Scale tool in `Tranform: path` mode (third icon in the `Transform:` line in the Tool options).

Comment: I'll second the suggestion to use Inkscape for your edit requirements. If you discover that your image is not a true SVG, and is raster instead, you can use the Trace Bitmap feature of Inkscape to convert it for your purposes.